# Which Dratini to focus on? How to focus on moveset?

Tags: pokemon-go

**Dratini A** = CP 72, **95.6%** IV (15 attack, 13 defense, 15 stamina), Dragon Breath & Twister

**Dratini B** = CP 414, **91.15%** IV (15 attack, 12 defense, 14 stamina), Dragon Breath & Twister

I have 125 Dratini candies and could get more somewhat easily since I know where its nest is. Should I stick with evolving the CP 72 Dratini since its IV is 96%? Though using the CP evolution calculator, the resulting Dragonite would only be around CP 265...

On the other hand, evolving the CP 414 Dratini with 91% IV  would produce a CP 1500 Dragonite

Also, I've been reading a lot of places on "focusing on moveset". But how do you focus on movesets if they are all random upon evolution?

Answer (score 1):

If stardust is a problem for you, I would choose the CP 414 Dratini. However, if you can easily get stardust from eggs or catching Pokemon with Pokeballs from farmed Pokestops, I would choose the CP 72. As is pointed out in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMtsIRp71mw/), a 4.5% IV advantage is actually a ((1.045^3)-1)% advantage, or about 14%, a huge difference. It may be more work in the short term, but the higher IV certainly may prove better in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Dragonite's base stats:

- Attack: 250
- Defense: 212
- Stamina: 182

Your Dratini with lower CP has a 1-point advantage in Defense (0.47% increase) and Stamina (0.55% increase), which is a drop in the bucket compared to its base stats. Choosing the higher CP one would mean a lot of saved dust, which is generally the higher priority.